# Best Ad Mediation for React Native (aside from AdMob)

Tags: react-native, mobile, ads, mobile-ad-mediation

I'm putting ads in my React Native app and I'm trying to find the best ad mediation platform to use.

I'm looking for one with:

1. United Auction, aka real time bidding
2. Their own React Native package or a package that's well maintained
3. At least 20 ad mediation networks, ideally with Facebook Audience Network
4. Multiple ad types, ideally with banner ads

**Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: Did you find any library?

Answer (score 2):

you can use [react-native-fbads](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-fbads). it is maintaining by `callstack` <3

```
yarn add react-native-fbads
```

1. United Auction, aka real time bidding
2. Their own React Native package or a package that's well maintained
3. At least 20 ad mediation networks, ideally with Facebook Audience
   Network
4. Multiple ad types, ideally with banner ads

it support all four features

Comment: Are you sure Facebook Audience Network supports ad mediation?  I don't see anywhere on their website that talks about ad mediation, where you can use Facebook Audience Network as the mediation platform for other ad networks

Comment: yes it support ads mediation https://github.com/callstack/react-native-fbads#setmediationservice

Comment: I didn't understand how to use it with mediation while it has a setting option.